# How can I practically quantitatively measure UVA and UVB intensity?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, semiconductor-physics, spectroscopy

I'm looking for a way to determine distinguish the UVA and UVB intensity from a UV source (sun or UV lamp).  A full-blown spectrum graph would be best, but a simple quantification of UVA (315-400 nm) and UVB (280-315 nm) would suffice.  I am looking to spend less than ~US$250 on this building this device.

Could I use photodiodes or photoresistors to accomplish this?

Comment: Not photoresistors but you can with photodiodes. This question is better suited for the Electrical Eng SE. But UV photodiodes are crazy expensive especially large area ones and you need to be able to calibrate them. Spectrum graph is out of the question since I think you either need many narrow UV interference filters or prisms and other optical equipment which are all ungodly expensive. A UVA and UVB photodiode and transimpedance amp are dirt cheap in comparison. At least half your budget will probably go into the photodiodes. As per expense, stay away from the need for filters and optics.

Comment: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/ancient-stars-how-does-spectrograph-work/

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods, one cheap and one expensive, that are used to do this in industry where UV light is used for curing adhesives and inks.

The first is called a *dosimetry puck* and is a squat cylinder several inches across with a photodetector and a display in it. You place it on a conveyor belt, run it under your UV light source, and read the measurement off the display. They cost between $300-600 depending on features.

The second (which requires calibration against a dosimetry puck) is called a *dosimetry tag* which is a self-adhesive sticker coated with a dye that changes color with cumulative UV dosage. They cost a few pennies each and come in die-cut sheets. You run one under the UV lamp and then compare its color to your calibration standard and read off the dose.